# qt widen QScrollBar when hover using StyleSheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qscrollarea

I'm trying to change the width of a vertical QScrollBar with a custom stylesheet like

```
QScrollBar:vertical 
{
     border: 2px solid grey;
     background: #32CC99;
     width: 10px;
     margin: 22px 0 22px 0;"
}
QScrollBar:vertical:hover { 
     background: red; 
     width: 25px ;
}
```

It doesn't work. Did I make any mistake? Can't we change the width of widget in run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing this by using the stylesheets alone.

You could create your own scrollbar and override the [`enterEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and [`leaveEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent) and change the stylesheet there.

You could also install an event filter to your existing scrollbar (you can get your scrollbar by using the [`QAbstractScrollArea::verticalScrollBar()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBar) function) and listen to the same events and change the stylesheet there.

Answer (score 3):

You should try

```
QScrollBar::handle:hover {
    background: red; 
    width: 25px;
}
```

It works for me